# How can print all chars present in rust using a simple loop?

Tags: rust

I'm going through rust data types and noticed rust `char` ranges from U+0000 to U+D7FF and U+E000 to U+10FFFF inclusive. What I'm trying to achieve is print all of these chars into the console by an incremental loop with a range (Idk if that's how its done). Below is the code snippet.

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    let ranges = [(0x0, 0xffD7FF), (0xE000, 0x10FFFF)];
    for range in ranges {
        let mut i = range.0;
        loop {
            i += 1;
            if i > range.1 {
                break;
            }
            print!(
                "{}",
                char::from_u32(i)
                    .expect(&format!("panic at {:x} and range: {:x} -> {:x}", i, range.0, range.1))
            );
            let _ = io::stdout().flush();
        }
    }
}
```

It manages to print a lot into the console but it panics out with the following message:
`'panic at d800 and range: 0 -> ffd7ff'`
Can someone please help me understand how can I acheive this.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not everything from `U+0000` to `U+D7FF` is a printable character, or even an assigned character at all. Furthermore, what humans usually perceive as characters are actually _extended grapheme clusters_, which comprise multiple unicode scalars. For example, the family emojis are made by combining the constituent people emojis with zero-width-joiners. Thus naively iterating the unicode scalars won't produce any of the family emoji. If you're trying to print a table of all the possible glyphs for a given typeface, you're better off iterating the typeface's file (`.otf` or whatever)

Answer (score 2):

Your boundary is wrong. `0xD7FF` = `0x00D7FF` != `0xffD7FF`

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};

fn main() {
    let ranges = [(0x0..=0x00D7FF), (0xE000..=0x10FFFF)];
    for range in ranges {
        for i in range {
            print!("{}", char::from_u32(i).expect(&format!("panic at {:x}", i)));
            let _ = io::stdout().flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Richard Neumann said, you define the first part of the range as the interval [`0x000000`;`0xFFD7FF`] (inclusive):

```rust
let ranges = [(0x0, 0xffD7FF), (0xE000, 0x10FFFF)];
```

This should instead be:

```rust
let ranges = [(0x0, 0x00D7FF), (0xE000, 0x10FFFF)];
```

Note that `0xffD7FF` has been replaced with `0x00D7FF`.

Running the adjusted program on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nej5jjW14) gives the following (truncated) output:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Etc.

---

Do also note – like Alexander said – that not every code point in this specific range is a graphical (visible) character. The most notorious example being the control characters in [U+0000;U+001F], which have varying effects (such as U+000A commencing a new line).

This also depends on your specified (fallback) fonts, and the symbol used for *missing* glyphs etc.